# Factor-loadings vs Variable-loadings

Tags: pca, terminology, factor-analysis

In PCA and Factor Analysis, there is the term **loadings**, which refers to **factor loadings** (onto the original variable).

Does the term (original) **variable loading** (onto the latent factor) exist?

Comment: Perhaps you could show some usage - I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a situation where terminology is being used interchangeably.  It is more customary to say that a variable "loads on a factor" or principal component (PC), rather than a factor loads on a variable (PC).  Specifically, however, it's the same thing.  Loadings are correlation coefficients, essentially between an original variable $X$ and a factor or principal component $F$.

It's better to get into the habit of saying that an "original $X$ variable loads on a factor (or PC) with loading 0.65" (and not ever saying a factor(PC) loads on a variable).

Comment: Thanks, but just to be clear I have another question: The interpretation of the loading is: 1. The higher the loading of a PC, the more influence it has in the formation of the variable. 2. The higher the loading of a variable, the more influence it has in the formation of the principal component score. 3. Both ? So you say the answer is 1?

Comment: If it matters, the longer post of mine regarding the question is: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/366970/fundamental-difference-between-pca-and-fa

Comment: Your answer seems to be in opposition to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218600/why-are-regression-coefficients-in-a-factor-analysis-model-called-loadings)...

Comment: The answer to the comment is 2. The higher the loading of a variable, the more influence it has in the formation of the principal component score.  For option 1, factors and PCs don't create variables, since all the data comes from the variables.