# How to theoretically motivate factor scores?

Tags: factor-analysis

For this question, I begin by explaining my factor model, and then ask how to theoretically motivate factor scores given my setup. I would also be very grateful for clarification about any mistakes I may be making in setting up my factor model or explaining factor scores, as I'm not an expert in this area.

**Model Setup**

I have data where $i$ indexes people and $q$ indexes questions. Performance of person $i$ on question $q$ is $X_{iq}$. I posit a model where performance is generated by two latent factors, $F_{ik}$, $k=1,2$, which are properties of people, through the following equation

$$X_{iq}=\beta_{q1}F_{i1} + \beta_{q2}F_{i2} + E_{iq}$$

where $\beta_{qk}$ measures how factor $k$ loads on question $q$, and $E_{iq}$ is the error term. I assume that $Cor(F_{i1},F_{i2})=0$, and $Cor(F_{ik},E_{iq})=0$ for every $k$ and $q$. In addition, estimation proceeds by maximum likelihood under the assumption that $F_{i1}$ and $F_{i2}$ are bivariate normal (across people $i$), each with mean zero and variance one; and the $E_{iq}$ are multivariate normal, each with mean zero and variance (uniqueness) $\psi_q = 1 - \beta_{q1}^2 - \beta_{q2}^2$. Putting these together, this implies that for each $q$, $X_{iq}$ is assumed to be standard normal (this motivates standardizing these variables in pre-processing).

**Factor Scores**

After estimating the factor model by maximum likelihood, I have estimates for $\beta_{q1}$ and $\beta_{q2}$, which I call $\hat{\beta}_{q1}$ and $\hat{\beta}_{q2}$. For further analysis, I would like to predict (something like a) $\hat{F}_{i1}$ and $\hat{F}_{i2}$, for individual people $i$. This leads me to consider factor scores.

ttnphns writes (https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/126985/137620) that, in general, factor scores are given by $\bf\hat{F} = XB$, where $\bf X$ is the data (analyzed variables -- test questions in my case) while $\bf B$ is a weight matrix. There are several different weight matrices. ttnphns writes (https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/126985/137620) that a "popular/traditional approach, sometimes called Cattell's, is simply averaging (or summing up) values of items which are loaded by the same factor." In non-matrix notation, I interpret this as

$$\hat{F}_{i1} = \sum_{q}{}{\hat{\beta}_{q1}X_{iq}}$$

and

$$\hat{F}_{i2} = \sum_{q}{}{\hat{\beta}_{q2}X_{iq}}$$

Thus, if the factor "loads heavily" in predicting whether the person gets a high score on the question (which is my interpretation of a large $\beta_{qk}$ in the original factor model), then the question score "loads heavily" in predicting whether the person has a high level of the factor in this factor score calculation.

This seems intuitive, but **what is the formal, theoretical justification for this approach?** If there is any? Can this approach be seen as a "best predictor" of the individual-level factors $F_{ik}$ in any sense? (Or is there an alternative approach that can be formally justified?)

Comment: You probably have noticed that in my answer you link to, factor loadings (which you notate $b$) are notated $a$ (A, in matrix form) while $b$ (B) is kept for factor score coefficients. My notation is a sort of established in literature and I might recommend to follow it.

Comment: Now, the Cattell's or "coarse" method of computation of factor scores proclaims: let B = A or = some trivial f(A). That is quite intuitive, straightforward decision. The question is - is it good enough?

Comment: p.s. The notation in my answer actually leaves letter P for the loadings, but also says that when factors are kept orthogonal, P=S=A. Also well known fact.

Comment: p.p.s. There is a link in my answer to another answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/191332/3277 where I tried to express my feeling why the "coarse method" (B=A) is inferior to a refined method (such as e.g. regression method).